# Filtering an array with an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const arrFilter = [{id:1},[],[]];
```

how can I filter the empty array in the above example, so that the result would be the object with an id only

Comment: That array contains mixed types; objects and arrays. What other sorts of values can it potentially hold? What code have you tried and how is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length of the array returned from [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to determine if objects, arrays or strings are empty however it won't work on numbers.

With that in mind, try this assuming that

- all empty objects, arrays and strings should be omitted
- everything else stays

```js
const arrFilter = [{id:1},[],[], "a string", "", 1, 0];

const nonEmpties = arrFilter.filter(
  (item) => typeof item === "number" || Object.keys(item).length > 0
);
  
console.log(nonEmpties);
```

Comment: Thank You sir I really appreciate it. Please I would love to get your social media handle so I can reach you.